# Can't get the value with public function in smart contract by a transaction from a non-contract-running node in a private blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Can anyone help with this...struggling me so much.

Context:
A private blockchain with all Geth1.5.9 + Go1.8.1

Three nodes. Two miners.

Node 1: Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (No mining, it is only to collect data as a sensor)

Node 2: Cloud Host with Ubuntu14.04

Node 3: Mac OX 10.12

A smart contract is running on Node 2, and I setup the `eth.accounts[0]` as the creator of the smart contract, which means `Instance.creator()` will be the address of `eth.accounts[0]` on Node 2.

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract PaperCopyright {
  struct Paper{
    string author;
    string fileHash;
    string title;
    uint date;
  }

  address public creator;

  Paper[] public papers;

  function PaperCopyright() {
    creator = msg.sender;
  }

  function add(string author,string file,string title) returns(bool) {
    if(msg.sender != creator) throw;
    papers.push(Paper({
        author: author,
        fileHash: file,
        title: title,
        date: now
    }));
    return true;
  }

  function edit(uint index,string author,string file,string title,uint  date) returns(bool) {
    if(msg.sender != creator) throw;
    papers[index] = Paper({
        author: author,
        fileHash: file,
        title: title,
        date: date
    });
    return true;
  }

  function (){
    throw;
  }
}
```

Interaction is Ok.

Check by `admin.peers` and they all shows two peers mutually.

Now,

Normal ether transaction is all good, no problem. I can find the ether successully transferred, and record can been found in the block.

If a transaction is delivered on Node 2, all good, no problem. Transaction record can been found in the block and I am able call `Instance.paper()` to obtain the return values stored on the chain.

**If a transaction is delivered on Node 1 or Node 3 (Not the node running the smart contract), wrong things happen.** Check the blocks infomation by `eth.getTransactionReceipt`, `eth.getTransaction`, `eth.getBlock`, we could find the parameters have been successfully put on the chain, which means this specific transaction should have succeeded. And of course, I check this by `txpool.status` and `eth.getBlockTransactionCount("pending")`, and there would be zero on each node. However, if I try to call a public function `Instance.papers()` in order for the return values, it shows `" Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:"`, which means the contract status has not been yet changed. I DONT'T think it is because of the non-synced chain issue across these three nodes since the transactionHash and transactionContent can be found inside the block and `eth.blockNumber` are exactly the same.

Of course I can be clearly base the fact that data has been successfully uploaded on chain on the existence of transaction record inside the block, but this is very weird for me, and I wish to call the public function directly to look up the data I put in my private chain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## Even if the contract throw an error the transaction is recorded

Assuming your transaction went well because there is one recorded on the chain is wrong.

You said node 2 is the owner of the contract and your contract works only when used with node 2.

It is because of  `if(msg.sender != creator) throw;` in your `edit` and `add` functions.

This just stop the execution of the function if someone which is not the owner execute the function and rollback any side effects of your function. But the transaction is still written on the Chain.

> Because we want to retain the atomicity of transactions, the safest thing to do is to revert all changes and make the whole transaction (or at least call) without effect.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#exceptions